# How to solve $\binom{n-k}{m-k} \approx A$ for positive $k$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How to find a positive integer $k$ satisfying   $\binom{n-k}{m-k} \approx A$ given $n,m,A$ ?

For example how to find $k$ satisfying $\binom{32-k}{7-k} \approx 260000$ ? Using trial and error I found that $k=1$ leads to $736000$ and $k=2$ leads to $142000$ and $142000 < 260000 < 736000$. I'm looking for $k$ leading to larger than desired value i.e. $k=1$.

Obviously, I'm not looking for the answer of this example, I'm looking for a way to find $k$ generally.

Comment: +1 I think we can find a suitable machinery algorithm by Maple using trial and error as you noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial coefficient is bounded by $1$ and $\binom{2n}{n}$ for some $n$.  In your example, this would be $\binom{50}{25}$ when $k=-18$, which is about $2^{50}/\sqrt{25 \pi} \approx 1.27 \cdot 10^{14}$, which is much bigger than $260000$.  Seeing the upper bound be larger than the desired value, one may then begin incrementing through $k$ from some start point, say, $k=0$.  The following relation is of value in incrementing:

$$\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n}{m} \binom{n-1}{m-1}$$

In this case, we find that $k=0$ produces $3365856$, while subsequent $k$ produces

$$\binom{31}{6}=\frac{7}{32}\binom{32}{7} = \frac{7}{32} (3365856) = 736281$$
$$\binom{30}{5}=\frac{6}{31}\binom{31}{6} = \frac{6}{31} (736281) = 142506$$

This is about as close as we'll get to the stated value.

Comment: Thanks. So do you see any algorithm or approximation finding $k$ leading to larger than the desired?

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: generally, not really.  I think this incremental method will get you to the closest $k$ fairly quickly and without overflow.  (You can use log binomials with this algorithm if your initial guess does overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inequality ${n-k \choose m-k} \leq (m/n)^k{n \choose m}$ to get a bound
$$
k \leq \frac{\log{n \choose m} - \log(A)}{\log(n/m)}.
$$

Comment: It think it is not a proper bound since for the example stated in the question it gives $k \leq -393898$

Comment: It should be $\log(A)$. I fixed the answer.